# Using 2d array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, 2d

I'm getting the error:

> "Ambiguity between 'game.Form1.WallCheckerArray' and
>   'game.Form1.WallCheckerArray'"

Because I use it twice. Why can't I use the same array name twice with different values?  My code is below. The array exists out of cordinates.

my array:

```
private int[,] WallCheckerArray = new int[28, 4];// <<----- was the problem
        int[,] WallCheckerArray = {
                                      {220,250,13,64},//1
                                      {24,58,24,55},//2
                                      {104,206,22,55},//3
                                      {264,370,22,55},//4
                                      {382,450,22,55},//5
                                      {24,92,74,109},//6
                                      {104,136,74,185},//7
                                      {136,206,114,138},//8
                                      {150,326,74,98},//9
                                      {225,255,98,140},//10
                                      {345,365,74,185},//11
                                      {275,355,114,138},//12
                                      {384,445,74,109},//13
                                      {104,136,200,270},//14
                                      {150,330,240,270},//15
                                      {225,255,270,315},//16
                                      {340,370,200,270},//17
                                      {20,85,285,305},//18
                                      {50,85,305,345},//19
                                      {104,214,285,315},//20
                                      {274,368,285,315},//21
                                      {378,445,285,305},//22
                                      {378,415,305,345},//23
                                      {24,195,365,375},//24
                                      {104,154,335,375},//25
                                      {165,339,335,345},//26
                                      {215,245,335,375},//27
                                      {265,445,365,375},//28
                                      {355,365,335,375}//29
                                  };


int i = 0;
for( i = 0; i < 29; i++)
{
    if (((x >= WallCheckerArray[i, 0] && x <= WallCheckerArray[i, 1]) && (y >= WallCheckerArray[i, 2] && y <= WallCheckerArray[i, 3])))//-----------------------------------}-
         {
            InsideWC();
            System.Console.WriteLine(WallCheckerArray[i, 1]);
         }
}
```

Comment: That error doesn't mean you used it twice, but that there are two instances of WallCheckerArray in the same form.

Comment: Don't use arrays and `for` loops like that. Create a proper data model instead.

Comment: i can't find it any where else in my code exept for this part.

Comment: Using Visual Studio?  In that piece of your code, right click the name `WallCheckerArray` and select `FindAllReferences`.

Comment: Did you name a control _WallCheckerArray_? Tip: At least use _for( i = 0; i < WallCheckerArray.GetLength(0); i++)_ to get the highbound for the first index

Comment: I got my problem thx :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A line of code like `int[,] WallCheckerArray = something` is read by the compiler as "Make a new `int[,]` named WallCheckerArray.  And the problem is, you do that twice in a row; you can't have two different variables with the same name.  If you don't give a variable an access modifier, the C# compiler will assume you wanted it to be `Private`.

To make your code work:

```
private int[,] WallCheckerArray = new int[28, 4];
        WallCheckerArray = {
                                 /* Your Data */
                           };
```

FYI: you can actually make your array and fill it with data in the same statement, like so:

```
private int[,] WallCheckerArray = {
                                      {220,250,13,64},
                                      {24,58,24,55},
                                      {104,206,22,55},
                                      // and so on
                                  };
```

This way, you don't have to worry about declaring the size of the array, it'll be handled for you.

Answer (score 0):

Had to delete "private int[,] WallCheckerArray = new int[28, 4];"